# AngularJS: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error for @ and <space>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My following code snippet is not working and I am continuously getting error. I am dynamically generating this content. But When it renders, I get errors.

I have tried escape(), but still it's not working.

$scope.teamInvites[index].teamInviteId has a value like 12334

tname has a value like Test Team 1

email has a value like test@email.com

```
 + "<a ng-click='deleteRow(" + rowID + "," + $scope.teamInvites[index].teamInviteId+")'>Delete</a> | "
                                  + "<a ng-click='reInvite(" + rowID + "," + tname + ","+ email+")'>ReInvite</a>"
```

Error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error
```

Whenever there is @ or space in a variable, I get this error.
 don't know what's the work around here. Otherwise it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the strings in the generated expression. So (just the 2nd line):

```
+ "<a ng-click='reInvite(" + rowID + ","\" + tname + "\",\"" + email + "\")'>ReInvite</a>"
//                                      ^             ^  ^              ^
//                                      |             |  |              |
//  look here --------------------------+-------------+--+--------------+
```

Comment: thank you, it's simple and it really solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to build your string with rather than escaping characters - with Array.prototype.join.

It's rather performant and used widely wihtin the Angular community - for string defined templates:

```
    var a = [
        "<a ng-click='deleteRow(", rowId, ",", $scope.teamInvites[0], ")", "'>Delete</a> | ",
        "<a ng-click='reInvite(", rowID, ",", tname, ",", email ,")'>ReInvite</a>"
    ].join(''); // Join to a string.
```

Comment: You are missing the point: The problem is not performance - the problem is that the expression inside the `ng-click` attribute is invalid. The reason it is invalid is that a string is not quoted. This solution suffers from the same bug (but perhaps it will crash a few microseconds faster).